# What is $implicit in angular 2?

Tags: angular, ng-template

How is the following keyword used in angular2 ng-templates

- What is the purpose of `$implicit` in angular 2 templates?
- What is relationship between `let-<attribute>` and `$implicit`?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You can define local variables on `ng-template` through `let-name`

When angular creates a template by calling `createEmbeddedView` it can also pass context that will be used inside `ng-template`

Using the key `$implicit` in the context object will set its value as default. So if we write:

```typescript
vcRef.createEmbeddedView(template, { $implicit: 'value' })
```

and we have the template

```html
<ng-template let-foo> 
 {{ foo }}
</ng-template>
```

then we can think about it like

```html
<ng-template let-foo="$implicit"> 
  {{ foo }}
</ng-template>
```

so `foo` will equal `value`

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/rL0LA9D2F9RQrDmDSaQ0?p=preview)**

On the other hand, if we have a context like:

```html
{ bar: 'value' }
```

we have to declare variables like:

```html
let-foo="bar"
```

Comment: Is there any way to declare multiple variables and use them?

Comment: Thanks, @yurzui very good explanation clear my all the doubts :)

Comment: Thank you very mutch to explanation, it is perfect, very good.

Answer (score 22):

For multiple variables, you should do something like below,
A template would be:

```
<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="template" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit: 'Hello', key2: 'value2', key3: 'value3'}"> </ng-template>
```

then

```
<ng-template #template let-default let-key2="key2" let-key3="key3">
{{default}}
{{key2}}
{{key3}}
</ng-template>
```

so, output will be,

```
default = Hello
key2 = value2
key3 = value3
```

Comment: I've just always disliked this $implicit structure. It's kind of unnatural and ambiguous. I get that they want to keep things convenient but the idea of "if you define any let-var on your template declaration and leave it blank, it will be given the $implicit value" is not explained well in the documentation. Maybe I have a problem with the documentation...

Answer (score 6):

If you have to pass only a variable to the template from the container where we are referencing it, we could use

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="deleteClient;context: firstName">
</ng-container>
```

And use it like this.

```
<ng-template #deleteClient let-client="firstName">
Are you sure? Want to remove {{ client }} !
</ng-template>
```

Where as If you have to pass the object it self to the template, we could use

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="deleteClient;context: { $implicit: client }"> 
</ng-container>
```

And use it like this.

```
<ng-template #deleteClient let-client>
Are you sure? Want to remove {{ client.firstName }} {{ client.lastName }}!
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 4):

I have used $implicit to pass value to ng-template, dynamically creating an anchor tag for the title.
$implicit is used to pass data to ng-template

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]=" col.bodyTemplate"
                        [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit: product}">
 </ng-container>

<ng-template #productTitle let-product> // let-product-> declaring local variable
    <a [routerLink]="['/products', product.Id]" [queryParams]="{searchText:searchText}">
        {{product.Title}}</a>
</ng-template>
```