# Angular2 components inside component

Tags: angular2-template

Can someone please tell me if I can achieve this in angular2+.

```
 <app-list-table [list]="myList">
    <app-list-column name="'Name'"></app-list-column>
    <app-list-column name="'Direction'"></app-list-column>
 </app-list-table>
```

Comment: Try to load based on selector component inside.

Comment: can't we achieve this using transclusion concept.

Answer (score 0):

1. In module import router module as

RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'name',
        component: NameComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'direction',
        component: DirectionComponent
      }
    ])

2. In list table component use selectors of sub components

Comment: Thanks. but I don't want to create different components for each child item. I think the solution will be <app-list-table> <ng-template **directive></ng-template>  <ng-template **directive></ng-template> <app-list-table>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45112717/angular-4-dynamic-template-with-interpolation