# Wrap Angular ngFor directive with another structural directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-directive

My AppComponent's template (bootstraped in the AppModule) is

```html
<div *myDir="let item of mySource">
  My Directive #{{item}}
</div>
```

where `mySource` is an object with `list` property

```
mySource = { list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] };
```

So, replacing `myDir` with `ngFor` (`*ngFor="let item of mySource.list"`) would give me

> My Directive #1 
>   My Directive #2 
>  
>   My Directive #3 
>   My Directive #4 
>   My Directive #5

I'm trying to implement `myDir` in pair with `myComponent` to provide a templated wrapper over `ngFor` Angular core directive to be able to pass `mySource` (instead of `mySource.list`) and achive the same result. Of course, the final goal is much more complex, but I need to solve this task in terms of minimal example... What is done?

**my.directive.ts**

```typescript
import { MyComponent } from './my.component';

@Directive({ selector: '[myDir][myDirOf]' })
export class MyDirective {
  private source;
  constructor(/* ... */) { }
  @Input() set myDirOf(source) {
    this.source = source;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    // dynamic wrapping with MyComponent
    const templateView = this.templateRef.createEmbeddedView({});
    const compFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyComponent);
    const componentRef = this.viewContainer.createComponent(compFactory, null, this.viewContainer.injector, [templateView.rootNodes]);
    // passing MyDir params to Mycomponent's instance
    componentRef.instance.source = this.source;
    componentRef.instance.template = this.templateRef;
  }
}
```

**my.component.ts**

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my',
  template: `
<div *ngFor="let item of source.list">
  <ng-template
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"
    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{
      item: item
    }">
  </ng-template>
</div>`
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  source;
  template;
  constructor() { }
}
```

The problem is that I can't pass `item` back to the host component's template, so currently I'm getting just 5 same lines containing "My Directive #" and `{{item}}` doesn't work. Looks like something's wrong with MyComponent's `ng-template`. It accepts the `template` but won't pass the `item`.

I created an editable [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xahby6) with my current situation. Also, here's a simple diagram of what I need:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$implicit` to pass data to `item`

**my.component.html**

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of source.list">
  <ng-template
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"
    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{
      $implicit: item
    }">
  </ng-template>

</div>
```

Your template

```html
<div *myDir="let item of mySource">
  My Directive #{{item}}
</div>
```

is equivalent to

```html
<ng-template myDir let-item [myDirOf]="mySource">
  <div>
    My Directive #{{item}}
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

but if template variable (let-item) doesn't have value then it takes `$implicit` by default

```html
<ng-template myDir let-item="$implicit" [myDirOf]="mySource">
  <div>
    My Directive #{{item}}
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fdhvjw?file=app/my/my.component.html)**

See also

- [What is $implicit in angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45055384/what-is-implicit-in-angular-2/45055768#45055768)
- [Angular2: How is ngfor expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752744/angular2-how-is-ngfor-expanded/38761068#38761068)